# Android Dialog not recognizing Spinner

Tags: android, dialog, spinner

I want to create a country spinner on a pop-up dialog but findViewById for my spinner is not being recognized. this is the line giving me an error:
            countryField = (Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.viewSpin);

```
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)   
   {
       switch (id) 
       {
            case DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY:
           // This shows how to add a custom layout to an AlertDialog 
                        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
                       final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.commentlayout,null);
                        return new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this)
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setTitle(R.string.app_name)
                        .setView(textEntryView)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.Submit,newDialogInterface.OnClickListener()               
                         {
                             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                                 //System.out.println("You want to submit");

                     nameField = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                     countryField = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.viewSpin);// error line
                     commentField = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.commentField);

                     //get message from message fields
                     String  name = nameField.getText().toString();
                     String  count = countryField.getSelectedItem().toString();
                     String  comm = commentField.getText().toString();

                     //check whether the name field is empty or not
                     if(name.length()>0) { 
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = newHttpPost("URL");

    try {
   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
   // nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "01"));
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country", count));
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment", comm));
   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
   httpclient.execute(httppost);

   nameField.setText(""); //reset the message text field
   //countryField.setText("");
   commentField.setText("");
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
       }

        ourBrow.reload();   
        }
       else {
      //display message if text field is empty
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"All fields are required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 } 
                             }
                         })
                 .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()  
                 {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
                     {    
                     /* User clicked cancel so do some stuff */

                         System.out.println("You have cancelled");
                     }
                 }).create(); 
            }
       return null;
       }
```

Comment: not being recognized means what? Is return `nullpointerexception`?

Comment: @gunaseelan it says: The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type DialogInterface

Comment: Why dont you use `textEntryView` like the following. `(Spinner) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.viewSpin);`

Answer (score 0):

it is called findVIEWbyid for a reason. it needs some reference to a View, not the dialogInterface

try replacing

```
countryField = (Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.viewSpin);
```

with

```
countryField = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.viewSpin);
```

Comment: The method getView() is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: hmmmm try some other get() then. maybe getActivity() or getContext(). hard to tell from distance.

Comment: the problem is that normally you get your widgets hooked up in onCreate() where you have the correct reference for your View already. Now you have to retrieve it manually.. somehow.